# What is the difference these match anything rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If i test with following examples then (1) and (2) behave very similarly so i can't distinguish the difference between them.

in case with the `% ::` rule, it seems to have some different behavior than `% :` but i can't figure it out for certain.

```
% :                        ------ (1)
    @echo % : $@

----------------------

.DEFAULT :                 ------ (2)
    @echo default : $@

----------------------

% ::                       ------ (3)
    @echo % :: $@
```

In the following example, `%.foo : %.bar` is a non-terminal
and also has a rule that match with the prerequisite `%.bar`
so i think the `make a.foo` command in prompt has to match with `%.foo : %.bar` rule
but it eventually match with `% ::` rule of even longer stem

```
%.foo : %.bar
    @echo target : $@

%.bar :
    @echo target : $@

% ::
    @echo % :: $@

------------------------

sh$ make a.foo 
% :: a.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

> i think the make a.foo command in prompt has to match with %.foo : %.bar rule but it eventually match with % :: rule of even longer stem

Now try this:

```
$ touch a.bar
$ make a.foo
target : a.foo
```

That is make refuses to recurse deeper into implicit rules if it has already guaranteed 1-step chain (but otherwise chain lengths do not matter). So normally you should use `.DEFAULT:` for a default recipe, while `%::` only alongside with some prerequisite (see builtin rules, for example).

I admit I was also surprised when I've discovered that. But it turns out that when [the manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html):

> If all prerequisites exist or ought to exist, or there are no prerequisites, then this rule applies.

It means "be lazy and cut recursion short when possible".